# distinct states in search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

In the book AI- a modern approach and the answer in this link:
[Search algorithm with avoiding repeated states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303528/search-algorithm-with-avoiding-repeated-states)

I have a question. I kinda understood how we got *2 d<sup>2</sup>* as number of distinct states. What I didn't get is the Geometrical approach. For your reference, I am showing the matrix and the solution.

```
6 5 4 3 4 5 6
5 4 3 2 3 4 5
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
3 2 1 0 1 2 3
2 3 2 1 2 3 4
5 4 3 2 3 4 5
6 5 4 3 4 5 6
```

In the above, you have *7×7* matrix, it contains all cells of of distance up to *3* from the center, as you can see - the number of reachable states by counting them and see it fits the formula:

```
#reachable_cells(0) = 2*0*1 + 1 = 1
#reachable_cells(1) = 2*1*2 + 1 = 5
#reachable_cells(2) = 2*2*3 + 1 = 13
#reachable_cells(3) = 2*3*4 + 1 = 25
```

This was answered by Amit, an engineer at Google.

Comment: What is your question? Below, you state your question is answered?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I wanted to understand how is he getting the results for #reachable_cells(d)? How is 2*d*(d+1) + 1 similar to 2d^2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that cells at the same distance form a diamond shape (a square at 45°).

When you look at the `3` occurrences, you have 4 sides, with a total of 4*3=12 cells:

6 5 4  `3`  4 5 6
5 4 `3` 2 `3` 4 5
4 `3` 2 1 2 `3` 4
`3` 2 1 0 1 2 `3`
2 `3` 2 1 2 `3` 4
5 4 `3` 2 `3` 4 5
6 5 4  `3`  4 5 6

For other distances we get this:

```
  distance   occurrences
  ----------------------
     0            1
     1            4
     2            8
     3           12
     ..
     n           4n
```

The formula **4n** is true for all **n**, except for **n=0**, when it is **1**.

Now, to know the number of distinct cells with a distance *up to and including* **n**, we get this table:

```
  distance   occurrences
  ----------------------
     0            1
     1            1+4
     2            1+4+8
     3            1+4+8+12
     ..
     n            1 + ∑4i, for i in [1..n]
```

Now **1 + ∑4i = 1+4∑i**, and that **∑i** is the [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), which means we can simplify to:

**1+4( ½n(n+1) ) = 1+2n(n+1)**, which is the formula you have given in the example:

```
#reachable_cells(0) = 2*0*1 + 1 = 1
#reachable_cells(1) = 2*1*2 + 1 = 5
#reachable_cells(2) = 2*2*3 + 1 = 13
#reachable_cells(3) = 2*3*4 + 1 = 25
  ...
#reachable_cells(n) = 2*n*(n+1) + 1
```

Comment: This is perfect. I understand. So just to know if I'm correct, for very large values of n, we reach the result 2*n^2?

Comment: It is like the last line in my answer: 2*n*(n+1)+1. Or the same is: 1 + 2*n + 2*n^2. But the most significant term is indeed 2*n^2. So you could say it is O(n^2) in Big-Oh notation.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you very much.